# The penrose inverse of augmented system

Tags: least-squares

Assume y is the solution to a least squares problem and X $\in$ $R ^{m x n}$, where m $\geq$ n. In addition, X will have a full column rank, could somebody please explain how to take the inverse of the following 2x2 block matrix in the least squares equation, where the matrix I am referring to is the first one the least squares equation?

[image: Least squares equation]

Comment: Thank you for the modification

Comment: I am not sure what the determinant would be because the D block is not invertible